# Converting multiple .txt files to .mat in the same folder

Tags: matlab, loops

I have many .txt files that contain n rows and 7 columns each delimited with whitespace. I want to convert each file to .mat file and save that in the same folder.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for file = files'
    data=importdata(file.name);
    save(file.name, 'data');
end
```

While this works for a single file, i want to do it programmably since the number of .txt files i have is very large:

```
data=importdata('myfile.txt');
save('myfile', 'data');
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: dir returns struct. You need to extract the number of files first and start your counter. then extract the content of each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for idx = 1:length(files)
   file_name = files(idx).name;
   fprintf("Processing File %s\n",file_name);
   data=importdata(file_name);
   [filepath,name,ext] = fileparts(fullfile(pwd,file_name));
   save([name '.mat'],'data');
end
```

dir creates a stucture which you need to index through so we create the for loop to start at 1 and keep going until all the elements of dir have been processed.
Note in the code, I've also added a section to split the file name (e.g file1.txt) in to the file name and extension. This is so we only use the name part and not the extension when creating the mat file.

Answer (score 2):

@scotty3785's answers worked well and also this worked for me in case somebody needs it:

```
files = dir('*.txt');
for i=1:length(files)
    data=importdata(files(i).name);
    save(erase(files(i).name,".txt"), 'data');
end
```